# Android format locale to ANSI NISO-Z39

Tags: android, locale

I need the locale formatted with the ANSI NISO-Z39 standard.
(it means for example "eng", "fre", "ger", etc.)

Here is how I get the locale  :

```
 Locale current = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
```

We can also get it with

```
     getDefaultLocale()
```

But how to format it please ?
Thanks

Comment: `String langISO3 = Locale.getDefault().getISO3Language();`

Comment: Yes, I was coming back to say that i've just found this method. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `String langISO3 = Locale.getDefault().getISO3Language();`

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getISO3Language()